# .htaccess rewrite url based on cookie variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, cookies

i'm trying to rewrite url to existing file dynamically.
This is the static example :

```
DirectoryIndex load.php live.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^cole$ live.php
```

as expected, this works fine, when any page in same root calls `cole`, it redirects to `live.php`.

Now, i want to redirect to page `live.php` but replace `cole` with cookie dynamic value.

I tried this :

```
DirectoryIndex yosh.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookieName=([^;]+) [NC]

RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ pimp.php [QSA,L]
```

It doen't work, just displays a 404 not found page. Note that i use WAMP.

Any idea on how to do that ?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to do what you require, however, you shouldn't be getting a 404, if `/pimp.php` exists? That code should rewrite _any_ URL, providing `cookieName` is set to _something_. So, if this is not working then I would debug this first (since the more complex code certainly won't work). Can you see `cookieName` in the request, with a _positive_ value?

Comment: _Aside:_ Is there any reason you are changing the `DirectoryIndex`? You don't need to set `pimp.php` as a `DirectoryIndex` in order to simply rewrite to it.

Comment: @MrWhite, pimp.php exist, in same directory as htaccess file. `DirectoryIndex` only apply to `yosh.php` . I let `pimp.php`on first line from previous test, but i thinks it doesn't matter on result, did it ?

Comment: I want to catch previously created cookie's value and use it as rewrited name of `pimp.php`. If `cookieName=user1` so, `user1` ==> `pimp.php`. For any value of `cookieName` that value redirects to `pimp.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} cookieName=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /%1/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule  ^ /sub/pimp.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: ok, i tried your code, but same result, url `http://localdomain.com/sub/cookieValue 404 Not found`. where cookieValue is the previously generated cookie value in same path.

Comment: It's because you use subfolder... Try now (without ^, and with pimp.php at root)

Comment: How to do it ? `pimp.php`is in the same subfolder and must be.

Comment: Add this name `/sub/pimp.php